# Regular Expression with wordpress shortcodes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find all shortcodes within a string which looks like this:

```
 [a_col] One

 [/a_col] 

 outside
 [b_col]

 Two

 [/b_col] [c_col]  Three  [/c_col]
```

I need the content (eg "Three") and the letter from the col (a, b or c)
Here's the expression I'm using

```
preg_match_all('#\[(a|b|c)_col\](.*)\[\/\1_col\]#m', $string, $hits);
```

but $hits contains only the last one.

The content can have any character even "[" or "]"

**EDIT:**

I would like to get "outside" as well which can be any string (except these cols). How can I handle that or should I parse this in a second step?

Comment: Wordpress has a function for that already, you don't need to re-invent the wheel. I bet it's better working than any of the suggested answers because wordpress knows what a shortcode is and what not - and in which order encapsulated ones should be processed. Take care.

Comment: Very true, I plan to try and restructure my plugin to use the build in shortcodes if possible, but unfortunately my plugin needs to extract the shortcode out of the post, have it formatted, then place it back in, and this has to occur in a set order. Hopefully I figure out a way, but for now I do it manually.

Comment: Agree, but this is for a custom editor and I need it this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will capture anything in the content, as well as attributes, and will allow any characters in the content.

```
<?php

$input = '[a_col some="thing"] One[/a_col]
[b_col] Two [/b_col] 
[c_col] [Three] [/c_col] ';

preg_match_all('#\[(a|b|c)_col([^\[]*)\](.*?)\[\/\1_col\]#msi', $input, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

**EDIT:**

You may want to then trim the matches, since it appears there may be some whitespace. Alternatively, you can use regex for removing the whitespace in the content:

```
preg_match_all('#\[(a|b|c)_col([^\[]*)\]\s*(.*?)\s*\[\/\1_col\]#msi', $input, $matches);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [a_col some="thing"] One[/a_col]
            [1] => [b_col] Two [/b_col]
            [2] => [c_col] [Three] [/c_col]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  some="thing"
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  One
            [1] =>  Two 
            [2] =>  [Three] 
        )

)
```

It might also be helpful to use this for capturing the attribute names and values stored in `$matches[2]`. Consider `$atts` to be the first element in `$matches[2]`. Of course, would iterate over the array of attributes and perform this on each.

```
preg_match_all('#([^="\'\s]+)[\t ]*=[\t ]*("|\')(.*?)\2#', $atts, $att_matches);
```

This gives an array where the names are stored in `$att_matches[1]` and their corresponding values are stored in `$att_matches[3]`.

Comment: Thanks, that perfectly fits my need. Also it's prepared for attributes

Comment: I added some info on attributes

Answer (score 1):

use `((.|\n)*)` instead of `(.*)` to capture multiple lines...

```
<?php
 $string = "
 [a_col] One

 [/a_col] 
 [b_col]

 Two

 [/b_col] [c_col]  Three  [/c_col]";
  preg_match_all('#\[(a|b|c)_col\]((.|\n)*)\[\/\1_col\]#m', $string, $hits);

  echo "<textarea style='width:90%;height:90%;'>";
  print_r($hits);
  echo "</textarea>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man! works as expected but I'll go with the solution from @AramKocharyan

Comment: Yes, his answer is very thorough! Even pre-empting possible future problems. I would go with his answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an environment I can test with here but you could use a look behind and look ahead assertion and a back reference to match tags around the content. Something like this.

```
(?<=\[(\w)\]).*(?=\[\/\1\])
```